# how to use @{Html.RenderPartial();} in razor view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, dhtmlx

I am using `asp.net MVC with Razor views`.
I am loading the tab content using Iframe,
Tab.cshtml is my partial view
I gave like

```
tabbar.setContentHref("a1","Home/Tab");
```

Instead of this I want to use my partial page using `@{Html.RenderPartial("Tab");}` 
If I give like

```
tabbar.setContentHref("a1","@{Html.RenderPartial("Tab");}");
```

It is showing error like
*The partial view 'Tab' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.*
can u tell me how to do this

Comment: `setContentHref` takes a url as a parameter. `Html.RenderPartial` creates a string of html. You are trying to pass a mack truck into a license plate. `RenderPartial` is NOT what you need. You are better off using a partial view with child action and passing it's url to `setContentHref`

Comment: hi,Is it possible to load partial page in the tab content

Comment: technically, you cannot load a page INTO the tab. The tab doesn't store one. You **can** use the tab to load a partial view if it has a child action. Partial Views with Child actions can be loaded by calling their Action's URL. This URL can be passed to your tabbar.